# How can I save these struct to a binary file?

Tags: c, file-io

I have two structs I am aiming to save to a binary file.

```
typedef struct {
    int height;
    int width;
    int resistance_count;
    Resistance** resistances; //contains a list of resistance*.
} Breadboard;

typedef struct {
    int start_cell_col;
    int end_cell_col;
    int cell_row;
    float resistance_value;
} Resistance;
```

I am somewhat unsure how I should be going about saving them. Since I need to keep track of the "resistance_count" variable to know how many resistances I will be saving, I have to save the breadboard first. To do that my attempt has been as follows:

```
bool save_breadboard(char* filename, Breadboard* bb_pointer) {
    errno_t error_code;
    FILE* fp_board;
    
    /* Opens board.bin to save the board struct on. */
    error_code = fopen_s(&fp_board, filename, "wb");
    if (error_code != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    size_t elements_written = fwrite(bb_pointer, sizeof(Breadboard), 1, fp_board);
    if (elements_written == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    fclose(fp_board);
    return true;
}
```

With my current attempt I see a problem that I am also saving all the "Resistance**" which is perhaps unnecessary. I don't know if there is a way I could skip saving the resistance pointer pointers. But I don't think it will cause problem when I eventually read from it.

To save resistances I'm running into problems. Here is what I do:

```
bool save_resistances(char* filename, Breadboard* bb_pointer) {
    errno_t error_code;
    FILE* fp_resistances;
    /* Opens resistances.bin to save the array of resistance pointers on. */
    error_code = fopen_s(&fp_resistances, filename, "wb");
    if (error_code != 0) {
        return false;
    }
    size_t elements_written = fwrite(bb_pointer->resistances, sizeof(Resistance),
                                      bb_pointer->resistance_count, fp_resistances);
    if (elements_written == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    fclose(fp_resistances);

    return true;
}
```

I am pretty sure that I will be saving the resistance pointer this way. I cannot check with binary files, but if I am would dereferencing the resistance pointer help?

```
size_t elements_written = fwrite(*bb_pointer->resistances, sizeof(Resistance),
                                 ^         bb_pointer->resistance_count, fp_resistances);
```

Any help in helping me understand reading/writing to binary files would be much appreciated.

Comment: A typical way to represent that in a binary format is to use `Resistance resistances[];` as the last member. Also, if it's in binary format, you might want to define a strict format that deals with padding where necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting close to the solution. Just a couple of things missing...

> With my current attempt I see a problem that I am also saving all the "Resistance**" which is perhaps unnecessary. I don't know if there is a way I could skip saving the resistance pointer pointers [...]

Yeah, it is unnecessary. Indeed when reading back you will have to discard it and overwrite it with a valid value. I wouldn't bother finding strange ways of skipping the pointer. I'd suggest writing out a `NULL` pointer instead to avoid mistakes when re-reading the data by doing something like:

```c
void *tmp = bb_pointer->resistances;
bb_pointer->resistances = NULL;
size_t elements_written = fwrite(bb_pointer, sizeof(Breadboard), 1, fp_board);
bb_pointer->resistances = tmp;
```

Now, coming to the part where you actually save all your structures, this is wrong:

```c
size_t elements_written = fwrite(bb_pointer->resistances, sizeof(Resistance),
                                      bb_pointer->resistance_count, fp_resistances);
```

And doing `*bb_pointer->resistances` is also wrong. You want to save each `Resistance` struct, but your `->resistances` is an array of pointers, so (1) saving the pointers (`bb_pointer->resistances`) is obviously wrong and (2) trying to save the structs as if they were contiguous in memory (`*bb_pointer->resistances`) is also wrong. The only thing you can do is loop over the array and dereference every single pointer, saving it separately:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < bb_pointer->resistance_count; i++) {
    if (fwrite(bb_pointer->resistances[i], sizeof(Resistance), 1, fp_resistances) != 1) {
        // handle error
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, remember that [`fwrite`](https://manned.org/fwrite.3) returns the number of elements written which should always be equal to the requested number, so in general you need to check for errors with `res != count`, not with `res == 0`:

```c
size_t elements_written = fwrite(bb_pointer, sizeof(Breadboard), 1, fp_board);
if (elements_written != 1) {
    return false;
}
```